# beautifulsoup: how to scrape multiple urls that end differently

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape this [dictionary](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugation) for it's different verbs. the verbs appear in this 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/' plus the verb . so,e.g : for verb 'hacer' we will have: https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hacer

I would like to scrape all possible links that contain the conjugation of each verb, and return them as a list of strings. so I did the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/' 

for i in url:
    reqs = requests.get(url + str())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

    urls = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        urls.append(link.get('href'))

    print(urls)
```

but i only get a few empty list as when I print urls.

expected output sample:

```
['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hacer', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/tener',...etc]
```

Comment: So you like to get the verbs out of the javascript variable? [check the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70578991/14460824) -- Is not that clear in the question and could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through a string when you loop through `url'. Look at this code:

```
url = 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/' 

for i in url:
    print(i)
```

This produces every letter of the URL:

```
h
t
t
p
s
:
/
/
w
w
w
<truncated>
```

You are also doing something wrong here:

```
reqs = requests.get(url + str())
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do but 'url + str()' is just the URL plus an empty string, which is the URL.

If you remove the for loop and unnecessary empty string, you get what I think you are trying to get:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/' 

reqs = requests.get(url + str())
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    urls.append(link.get('href'))

print(urls)
```

This produces:

```
['/', '/learn', '/translation', '/conjugation', '/vocabulary', '#', '/translation', '/conjugation', '/vocabulary', '/guide', '/pronunciation', '/wordoftheday', '/learn', '/guide/spanish-present-tense-forms', '/guide/spanish-present-progressive-forms', '/guide/spanish-preterite-tense-forms', '/guide/spanish-imperfect-tense-forms', '/guide/simple-future-regular-forms-and-tenses', '/guide/spanish-present-subjunctive', '/guide/commands', '/guide/spanish-imperfect-subjunctive', '/guide', '/drill?drill_start_source=conjugation%20hubpage', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spanishdict.spanishdict&referrer=utm_campaign%3Dadhesion', '/wordoftheday', '/translate/patinar', '/', 'https://www.ingles.com/verbos', 'https://www.curiositymedia.com/', 'https://help.spanishdict.com/', '/company/privacy', '/company/tos', '/sitemap', '/', 'https://www.ingles.com/verbos', '/translation', '/conjugation', '/vocabulary', '/learn', '/guide', '/wordoftheday', 'https://www.curiositymedia.com/', '/company/privacy', '/company/tos', '/sitemap', 'https://help.spanishdict.com/', 'https://help.spanishdict.com/contact', 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/SpanishDict/92805940179', 'https://twitter.com/spanishdict', 'https://www.instagram.com/spanishdict/', 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spanishdict/id332510494', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spanishdict.spanishdict&referrer=utm_source%3Dsd-footer']
```

Is this list of links what you were aiming for?

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, but as for the output, i was expecting something like the following: [https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hacer', https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/tener',...]

Comment: Those pages are not linked to in the source of https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate so you are not going to get them with requests + BeautifulSoup. They appear with JavaScript when you click the search box, so you would have to use a library like Selenium. 

Alternatively, you could start at a page like 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hacer', and then crawl through the links you find that start with /conjugate, e.g. 
`urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.get('href').startswith("/translate"):
        urls.append(link.get('href'))`
But you may miss pages.

Comment: thank you for the tip, i will try selenium then

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Hopfully get your point - If so, question should be imporoved. To get the information from the javascript, you can parse the response using regex:

```
import requests
import json
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugation')
m = re.search(r'window.SD_COMPONENT_DATA = ({.*})', r.text)
['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/'+w for x in json.loads(m.group(1))['searchQuickLinkSections'] for w in x['words']]
```

##### Output

```
['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/tener',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hacer',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ser',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/estar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/haber',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/poder',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/decir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/cerrar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/mentir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/dormir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/recordar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/seguir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/medir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/adquirir',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/jugar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/vestirse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/divertirse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/acostarse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ponerse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/despertarse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/sentirse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/levantarse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/sentarse',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/gustar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/alegrar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/quedar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/encantar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/parecer',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/faltar',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/doler',
 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/interesar']
```

---

Getting your expected output you should have a list of verbs. While there is no source provided in your question a good start to generate such these information I used the list [`verbs-top-500`](https://www.spanishdict.com/lists/1690101/verbs-top-500) and a list comprehension.

For all `<a>` that contains `translate` in its `href` it concat your url and the verb that is text in the direct child `<div>`of `<a>`:

```
['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/'+a.div.text for a in soup.select('a[href*="translate"]')]
```

#### Example

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.spanishdict.com/lists/1690101/verbs-top-500'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

urls = ['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/'+a.div.text for a in soup.select('a[href*="translate/"]')]
```

#### Output

```
['https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/procurar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/podar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/pillar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/perrear', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/perfeccionar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/perdonar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/pegar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/pasear', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ordenar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ondear', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ojalar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ocultar', 'https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/nombrar',...]
```